# Can "economy" and "economics" be used interchangeably?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I know "economy" and "economics" are related terms that do not mean the same thing. But I am having trouble understanding a question asking me to state how globalization has affected the world's "economics". And I am wondering if economics here is used to actually mean "economy".

Many thanks

Comment: You'll have to give a full context before anyone can help you much.  *Economy* is the word for the totality of commerce in some sphere; economics is the study of economy.   Generally, they wouldn't be interchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

As well as the study of economies, there seems to be another less common meaning of economics:

> *economic conditions* http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/economics
>
> *economic matters, especially relevant financial considerations* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/economics
>
> *the condition of a region or group as regards material prosperity.* Google definition

This seems to be the meaning the author intended.

Comment: Yes, I believe the author meant *economic conditions*.

Comment: It wouldn't be unusual for the term *economics* to be used loosely in that way, even though it is not strictly appropriate.